# Subset to remove duplicate id and condition

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, subset

If this is my dataset

```
Id   Weight   Category
1    10.2     Pre
1    12.1     Post
2    11.3     Post
3    12.9     Pre
4    10.3     Post
4    12.3     Pre
5    11.8     Pre
```

How Do I get rid of duplicate IDs that are also Category=Pre. My final expected dataset would be

```
Id   Weight   Category

1    12.1     Post
2    11.3     Post
3    12.9     Pre
4    10.3     Post
5    11.8     Pre
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `by`, split `dat` by `Id` and select `Post`, then `rbind` result.

```
do.call(rbind, by(dat, dat$Id, function(x) 
  if (nrow(x) == 2)  x[x$Category == 'Post', ] else x))
#   Id Weight Category
# 1  1   12.1     Post
# 2  2   11.3     Post
# 3  3   12.9      Pre
# 4  4   10.3     Post
# 5  5   11.8      Pre
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- read.table(header=T, text='
                  Id   Weight   Category
1    10.2     Pre
1    12.1     Post
2    11.3     Post
3    12.9     Pre
4    10.3     Post
4    12.3     Pre
5    11.8     Pre
                  ')
```

Answer (score 3):

You may arrange the data and then use `distinct`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% arrange(Id, Category) %>% distinct(Id, .keep_all = TRUE)

#  Id Weight Category
#1  1   12.1     Post
#2  2   11.3     Post
#3  3   12.9      Pre
#4  4   10.3     Post
#5  5   11.8      Pre
```

This works because `'Pre' > 'Post'`.

Comment: I have a `date` column in my true dataset and when I run your solution it is throwing an error` Internal error in `date_valideate()` : Corrupt Date with unknown type character.`

Comment: I don't see a reason why a date column would change anything in the answer. Try restarting R or providing a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `filter` after grouping and arranging using `first()` as `Post` comes before `Pre`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Id) %>% 
  arrange(Id, Category) %>% 
  filter(Category ==first(Category))
```

output:

```
     Id Weight Category
  <int>  <dbl> <chr>   
1     1   12.1 Post    
2     2   11.3 Post    
3     3   12.9 Pre     
4     4   10.3 Post    
5     5   11.8 Pre
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(df[with(df, order(Id, Category == 'Pre')),], !duplicated(Id))
  Id Weight Category
2  1   12.1     Post
3  2   11.3     Post
4  3   12.9      Pre
5  4   10.3     Post
7  5   11.8      Pre
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L), Weight = c(10.2, 
12.1, 11.3, 12.9, 10.3, 12.3, 11.8), Category = c("Pre", "Post", 
"Post", "Pre", "Post", "Pre", "Pre")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```